# Razor Pages - handling pagination with multiple submit buttons or multiple forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a relatively simple pagination in my web application. Note that this is strictly using asp.net core and I'll rebuild it down the line as a SPA.

I have already implemented pagination but am confused about two things:

- How multiple submit buttons works the way it does
- The correct approach (i.e. should I use the multi-button option or forms or change my approach completely)

**Multiple Submit Buttons**

```
 <form method="post">
        <input type="number" asp-for="PageSize" />
        @if (Model.pageParameters?.PreviousPageLink != null)
        {
            <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="" asp-route-pageNum="@(Model.pageParameters.CurrentPage - 1)" class="btn btn-default">Previous</button>
        }
        @for (var i = 1; i <= Model.pageParameters?.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            <button type="submit" asp-route-pageNum="@i" class="btn btn-default">@i</button>
        }
        @if (Model.pageParameters?.NextPageLink != null)
        {
            <button type="submit" asp-route-pageNum="@(Model.pageParameters.CurrentPage + 1)" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
        }
    </form>
```

I found the above approach after looking at some pagination examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#write-a-basic-form. Instead of multiple forms, multiple submit buttons are used with separate `asp-route-{value}` attributes.

I was not aware that this could be used on buttons. I thought this was more for link tags and ensuring that the correct data got passed. Yet above approach works as it transforms the buttons as below:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" formaction="/MeetingMinutes/1">1</button>
```

How does the transformation take place with using the `asp-route-{value}` attribute? I'm aware that the form will by default post back to the same page as no action is specified. *But how is a formaction attribute being generated so that it works correctly?*

---

**Multiple Forms Approach**

Its essentially the same approach as above but using multiple forms:

```
 @for (var i = 1; i <= Model.pageParameters?.TotalPages; i++)
    {
        <form method="post">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">@i</button>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="PageNum" value="@i" />
            <input type="number" asp-for="PageSize" />
        </form>
    }
```

I'm not too keen on this approach as it uses multiple forms which might bloat the amount of HTML being generated. But wanted to check if this is a completely wrong approach or if it has its purpose.

**Note:** The only reason I didn't use anchor tags to generate pagination links is because I want the user to be able to control the amount of values returned. Hence the reason for the `<input type="number" asp-for="PageSize" />` (I'll change this to a selectlist most likely). If its possible to handle getting user input via (something like `value="@Userenteredvalueforfield"`), I'll change everything to anchor tags.

Comment: Maybe this helps you https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN This is not using separate handler methods though. It's all being posted to the same handler. My question was more akin to how asp-route-{value} transforms a button element to a formaction and if my initial approach (of a single form) was correct. I'd love to change everything to an anchor tag but due to the limitation of not being able to handle user input I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

The transformation is occurring with the use of the asp-route Tag Helper attribute: [Tag Helpers in forms in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.2)